# how can I succesfully install rasa through Pip install rasa?

Tags: installation, rasa, rasa-nlu

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQgD1.png)
guys i have give I am new in this chatbot project
I also add

Answer (score 1):

Since i'm not allowed to comment yet... It seems you don't have the rights to install it on your computer.
Have you tried this?

```sh
pip3 install --user rasa
```

Comment: I did... I run the CMD as administrator. it says it doesn't recognize my username. even when i copy my username from 'net user'.